# Search a string for a given key

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been doing some more `CodeEval` challenges and came across one on the [*hard*](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/28/) tab.

> You are given two strings. Determine if the second string is a substring of the first (Do NOT use any substr type library function). The second string may contain an asterisk(*) which should be treated as a regular expression i.e. matches zero or more characters. The asterisk can be escaped by a \ char in which case it should be interpreted as a regular '*' character. To summarize: the strings can contain alphabets, numbers, * and \ characters.

So you are given two strings in a file that look something like this: `Hello,ell` your job is to figure out if `ell` is in `hello`, what I do:

I haven't quite gotten it perfect, but I did get it to the point where it passes and works with a 65% complete. How it runs through the string, and the key, and checks if the characters match. If the characters match, it appends the character into a list. After this it divides the length of the string by 2 and checks if the length of the list is either greater than, or equal to half of the string. I figured half of the string length would be enough to verify if it indeed matches or not. Example of how it works:

```
h == e -> no
e == e -> yes -> list
l == e -> no
l == e -> no
...
```

My question is what can I do better to the point where I can verify the wildcards that are said above?

```
import sys


def search_string(string, key):
    """ Search a string for a specified key.
    If the key exists out put "true" if it doesn't output "false"
    >>> search_string("test", "est")
    true
    >>> search_string("testing", "rawr")
    false"""
    results = []
    for c in string:
        for ch in key:
            if c == ch:
                results.append(c)
    if len(string) / 2 < len(results) or len(string) / 2 == len(results):
        return "true"
    else:
        return "false"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as data:
        for line in data.readlines():
            data_list = line.rstrip().split(",")
            search_key = data_list[1]
            word = data_list[0]
            print(search_string(word, search_key))
```

Comment: Can I use the `.split()` function?

Comment: `s='string'
print 'st'in s
`

Comment: @johnsmith If you'd read the description, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution to this problem. You've said "*Do NOT use any substr type library function*", I'm not sure If some of the functions I used are allowed or not, so tell me if I've broken any rules :D

Hope this helps you :)

```
def search_string(string, key):
    key = key.replace("\\*", "<NormalStar>") # every \* becomes <NormalStar>
    key = key.split("*") # splitting up the key makes it easier to work with
    #print(key)

    point = 0 # for checking order, e.g. test = t*est, test != est*t
    found = "true" # default
    for k in key:
        k = k.replace("<NormalStar>", "*") # every <NormalStar> becomes *
        if k in string[point:]: # the next part of the key is after the part before
            point = string.index(k) + len(k) # move point after this
        else: # k nbt found, return false
            found = "false"
            break

    return found


print(search_string("test", "est"))       # true
print(search_string("t....est", "t*est")) # true
print(search_string("n....est", "t*est")) # false
print(search_string("est....t", "t*est")) # false
print(search_string("anything", "*"))     # true
print(search_string("test", "t\*est"))    # false
print(search_string("t*est", "t\*est"))   # true
```

Comment: I don't think you've broken any rules. Wonder why this question is downvoted.. Anyways, that's awesome, thank you, can you explain why you use `<NormalStar>` though that's kind of confusing me?

Comment: I've made sure that when the key contains a `\*` that it is not used to split the key, I replace every `\*` with `<NormalStar>`, then I change it back afterwards. For example `5 \* 6` will become `5 <NormalStar> 6` (which won't be split up), then it will become `5 * 6`.

Comment: That makes sense, that's a pretty smart idea. Thank you again!